# Pandas: How to return the rows where col value is greater than 'x' in rolling window

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large df and I am trying find all rows where the value in a specific column is above a given number but within a window of say 3 rows and returning only the rows with the highest value over the given number.

```
A    B    C    D    E
1    5    9    10   15
2    4    7    12   16
3    3    5    10   18
4    2    3    15   17
5    1    1    10   14
6    5    9    17   13
7    4    7    10   14
8    3    5    19   19
9    2    3    10   18
10   4    7    5   14
11   3    5    6   19
12   2    3    7   18
```

If I wanted to do this with the above example for column D, where the value must be above 11, the output would be.

```
A    B    C    D    E
2    4    7    12   16
6    5    9    17   13
8    3    5    19   19.
```

What would be the best way to go about this?

I've tried:
 `df.rolling(3,win_type=None, on='D')` 
but can't find a way to include the greater than condition.

Any help is appreciatted. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how do I calculate a rolling idxmax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40101130/how-do-i-calculate-a-rolling-idxmax)

Comment: Not quite, I don't want to return the max in each window as sometimes the values will be below the minimum value I want to set.

Comment: I think any pandas method will not help, you should go for simple for loop parsing. If you want it then I can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edited**:
Try this:

```
threshold = 11
window = 3
df['r'] = np.floor(df.index / window)
print(df.groupby('r').apply(lambda x : (x.loc[x['D'] == x['D'].max() ,:]) if x['D'].max() > threshold else None))
```

You can drop column 'r' after usage.

Output:

```
      A  B  C   D   E    r
r                          
0.0 1  2  4  7  12  16  0.0
1.0 5  6  5  9  17  13  1.0
2.0 7  8  3  5  19  19  2.0
```

Comment: This worked! Although, I don't quite understand it. Thank you!

Comment: made group for the desired window, and desired filteration for the group is achieved by `groupby` and `lambda`