# Using a Pandas Rolling window to find the maximum whilst keeping the entire row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
timestamp                  group   score
2020-06-03 09:01:27+00:00  A       13
2020-06-03 09:05:18+00:00  B       14
                           C       15
2020-06-03 09:05:39+00:00  A       12
2020-06-03 09:05:45+00:00  B       16
2020-06-03 09:07:09+00:00  C       17
2020-06-03 09:08:43+00:00  A       26
```

I would like to take a rolling window of size three and find the maximum score.
The part I'm struggling with is how to keep the `timestamp` and  `group` information.
The expected output would be:

```
timestamp                  group   score
2020-06-03 09:05:18+00:00  C       15
                           C       15
2020-06-03 09:05:45+00:00  B       16
2020-06-03 09:07:09+00:00  C       17
2020-06-03 09:08:43+00:00  A       26
```

So importantly, the first row in the output is duplicated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idea is get indices for maximal values of `score` by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40102656) solution and then pass to [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
N = 3
s = df['score']
maxidx = (s.values[np.arange(s.size-N+1)[:,None] + np.arange(N)]).argmax(1)
df = df.loc[s.index[maxidx+np.arange(maxidx.size)]]
print (df)
                                 score
timestamp                 group       
2020-06-03 09:05:18+00:00 C         15
                          C         15
2020-06-03 09:05:45+00:00 B         16
2020-06-03 09:07:09+00:00 C         17
2020-06-03 09:08:43+00:00 A         26
```

Or:

```
N = 3   
s = df['score']
#https://stackoverflow.com/a/40101614
idx = s.index[s.rolling(N).apply(np.argmax)[(N-1):].astype(int)+np.arange(len(s)-(N-1))]
df = df.loc[idx]
```