# Rolling idxmin/max for pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, rolling-computation

I believe the following function is a working solution for pandas DataFrame rolling argmin/max:

```
import numpy as np

def data_frame_rolling_arg_func(df, window_size, func):
    ws = window_size
    wm1 = window_size - 1
    return (df.rolling(ws).apply(getattr(np, f'arg{func}'))[wm1:].astype(int) +
            np.array([np.arange(len(df) - wm1)]).T).applymap(
                lambda x: df.index[x]).combine_first(df.applymap(lambda x: np.NaN))
```

It is inspired from [a partial solution for rolling idxmax on pandas Series](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40101614/3246135).

Explanations:

- Apply the numpy argmin/max function to the rolling window.
- Only keep the non-`NaN` values.
- Convert the values to `int`.
- Realign the values to original row numbers.
- Use `applymap` to replace the row numbers by the index values.
- Combine with the original `DataFrame` filled with `NaN` in order to add the first rows with expected `NaN` values.

```py
In [1]: index = map(chr, range(ord('a'), ord('a') + 10))

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame((10 * np.random.randn(10, 3)).astype(int), index=index)

In [3]: df                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
Out[3]: 
    0   1   2
a  -4  15   0
b   0  -6   4
c   7   8 -18
d  11  12 -16
e   6   3  -6
f  -1   4  -9
g   6 -10  -7
h   8  11 -25
i  -2 -10  -8
j   0  10  -7

In [4]: data_frame_rolling_arg_func(df, 3, 'max')                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
Out[4]: 
     0    1    2
a  NaN  NaN  NaN
b  NaN  NaN  NaN
c    c    a    b
d    d    d    b
e    d    d    e
f    d    d    e
g    e    f    e
h    h    h    g
i    h    h    g
j    h    h    j

In [5]: data_frame_rolling_arg_func(df, 3, 'min')                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
Out[5]: 
     0    1    2
a  NaN  NaN  NaN
b  NaN  NaN  NaN
c    a    b    c
d    b    b    c
e    e    e    c
f    f    e    d
g    f    g    f
h    f    g    h
i    i    g    h
j    i    i    h
```

My question are:

- Can you find any mistakes?
- Is there a better solution? That is: more performant and/or more elegant.

And for pandas maintainers out there: it would be nice if the already great pandas library included rolling idxmax and idxmin.

Comment: A little bit of self-critique after testing on real data: the OP's implementation won't work with only `NaN` values in a column for a window, and it seems to take orders of magnitude longer than a rolling max. Unless the performance part can be solved I will need to limit the function to a few rows (which is what I need), and I will have to solve the `NaN`issue.

Answer (score 0):

The `NaN` issue I mentioned in a comment to the OP can be solved in the following manner:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


def data_frame_rolling_idx_func(df, window_size, func):
    ws = window_size
    wm1 = window_size - 1
    return (df.rolling(ws, min_periods=0).apply(getattr(np, f'arg{func}'),
                                                raw=True)[wm1:].astype(int) +
            np.array([np.arange(len(df) - wm1)]).T).applymap(
                lambda x: df.index[x]).combine_first(df.applymap(lambda x: np.NaN))


def main():
    index = map(chr, range(ord('a'), ord('a') + 10))
    df = pd.DataFrame((10 * np.random.randn(10, 3)).astype(int), index=index)
    df[0][3:6] = np.NaN
    print(df)
    print(data_frame_rolling_arg_func(df, 3, 'min'))
    print(data_frame_rolling_arg_func(df, 3, 'max'))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Result:

```sh
$ python demo.py 
      0   1   2
a   3.0   0   7
b   1.0   3  11
c   1.0  15  -6
d   NaN   2 -16
e   NaN   0  24
f   NaN   0  14
g   2.0   0   4
h  -1.0 -11  16
i  17.0   0  -2
j   3.0  -5  -8
     0    1    2
a  NaN  NaN  NaN
b  NaN  NaN  NaN
c    b    a    c
d    d    d    d
e    d    e    d
f    d    e    d
g    e    e    g
h    f    h    g
i    h    h    i
j    h    h    j
     0    1    2
a  NaN  NaN  NaN
b  NaN  NaN  NaN
c    a    c    b
d    d    c    b
e    d    c    e
f    d    d    e
g    e    e    e
h    f    f    h
i    i    g    h
j    i    i    h
```

The handling of `NaN` values is a little subtle. I want my rolling `idxmin/max` function to cooperate well with the regular `DataFrame` rolling `min`/`max` functions. These, by default, will generate a `NaN` value as soon as the window input shows a `NaN` value. And so will the rolling `apply` function by default. But for the apply function, that is a problem, because I will not be able to transform the `NaN` value into an index. However this is a pity, since the `NaN` values in the output show up because they can be found in the input, so the `NaN` value index in the input is what I would like my rolling `idxmin/max` function to produce. Fortunately, this is exactly what I will get if I use the following combination of parameters:

- `min_periods=0` for the pandas `rolling` function. The `apply` function will then get a chance to produce its own value regardless of how many `NaN` values are found in the input window.
- `raw=True` for the `apply` function. This parameter ensures that the input to the applied function is passed as a numpy array instead of a pandas Series. `np.argmin/max` will then return the index of the first input `NaN` value, which is exactly what we want. It should be noted that without `raw=True`, i.e. in the pandas Series case, `np.argmin/max` seems to ignore the `NaN` values, which is NOT what we want. The nice thing with `raw=True` is that it should improve performance too! More about that later.

Comment: Measurements on this solution seem to indicate that the running time for calculating rolling `idxmin` /`idxmax` in this way is five times the running time necessary to calculate the corresponding rolling `min`/`max`. This is quite high, but not quite "orders of magnitude longer". I guess this is thanks to `raw=True`. I will use this for now, but if anyone has a better proposition, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 0):

The solution in my previous answer manages to give proper index values for `NaN` input values, but I have realized that this is most probably not what a native pandas rolling `idxmin`/`idxmax` would do by default. By default, it would produce a `NaN` value if there is one or more `NaN` values in the window.

I came up with a variant of my solution, which does that:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


def transform_if_possible(func):
    def f(i):
        try:
            return func(i)
        except ValueError:
            return i
    return f


int_if_possible = transform_if_possible(int)


def data_frame_rolling_idx_func(df, window_size, func):
    ws = window_size
    wm1 = window_size - 1

    index_if_possible = transform_if_possible(lambda i: df.index[i])

    return (df.rolling(ws).apply(getattr(np, f'arg{func}'), raw=True).applymap(int_if_possible) +
            np.array([np.arange(len(df)) - wm1]).T).applymap(index_if_possible)


def main():
    print(int_if_possible(1.2))
    print(int_if_possible(np.NaN))
    index = map(chr, range(ord('a'), ord('a') + 10))
    df = pd.DataFrame((10 * np.random.randn(10, 3)).astype(int), index=index)
    df[0][3:6] = np.NaN
    print(df)
    print(data_frame_rolling_idx_func(df, 3, 'min'))
    print(data_frame_rolling_idx_func(df, 3, 'max'))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Results:

```sh
1
nan
      0   1   2
a  15.0  -2  13
b  -6.0  -4  -3
c -12.0  -7  -8
d   NaN   0  -4
e   NaN  -1 -11
f   NaN  -9  10
g  -1.0  24   1
h -15.0  14 -16
i   7.0  -4  14
j  -1.0   4  10
     0    1    2
a  NaN  NaN  NaN
b  NaN  NaN  NaN
c    c    c    c
d  NaN    c    c
e  NaN    c    e
f  NaN    f    e
g  NaN    f    e
h  NaN    f    h
i    h    i    h
j    h    i    h
     0    1    2
a  NaN  NaN  NaN
b  NaN  NaN  NaN
c    a    a    a
d  NaN    d    b
e  NaN    d    d
f  NaN    d    f
g  NaN    g    f
h  NaN    g    f
i    i    g    i
j    i    h    i
```

To achieve my goal, I am using two functions to transform values into integers, and row numbers into index values, respectively, which leave `NaN` unchanged. I construct these functions with the help of a common closure, `transform_if_possible`. In the second case, since the index transformation is dependent on the `DataFrame`, I construct the transformation function from a local lambda function.

Apart from these aspects, the solution is similar to [my previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65533850/3246135), but since `NaN` is explicitly handled, I know longer need a special handling of the first `window_size - 1` rows, so the code is a little shorter.

A nice side effect of this solution is that the running time seems to be lower: a little over three times the running time of the corresponding rolling `min`/`max`, instead of five times.

All in all, a better solution I think.

Comment: I just discovered the option `a_action='ignore'` in `DataFrame.applymap` in pandas 1.2, which I automatically get if I install my virtualenv with Python 3.9. This is great, since it makes my explicit 'NaN' handling above redundant, and the resulting code's running time is divided by 2.5 or so! The code adaptation is left as an exercise, since I seem to be the only one interested by this issue anyway...

Answer (score 0):

A monotonic deque can solve it in O(N),

```
def get_rolling_idxmin(l_input:[], window_size:int) -> [(int,float)]:
    res = []
    deq:[(int, float)] = []
    n = len(l_input)
    for i in range(n):
        v = l_input[i]
        if len(deq) and (i - deq[0][0]) >= window_size:
            deq.pop(0)
        while len(deq) and v <= deq[-1][1]: 
            deq.pop(-1)
        deq.append((i,v))
        res.append((deq[0][0],deq[0][1]))
    return res

l_min = get_rolling_idxmin(df.bp1[::-1].to_list(), 50)
df_min = pd.DataFrame(l_min, columns=['index_min', 'value_min'])
df_min['index_min'] = df_min.shape[0]-1-df_min.index_min
df_min = df_min[::-1]
df_min.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
# print(df_min)
df = pd.concat([df,df_min], axis=1)
```