# pandas DataFrame rolling apply np.argmin and manual np.argmin give different results

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, rolling-computation

### Edit: reduction to a simpler case

```py
In [1]: np.argmin(pd.Series([-6.0, 7.0, np.NaN]))
Out[2]: 0

In [2]: pd.Series([-6.0, 7.0, np.NaN]).rolling(3).apply(np.argmin)                                                                                                                                                                                                               
Out[2]: 
0   NaN
1   NaN
2   NaN
dtype: float64

In [3]: pd.Series([-6.0, 7.0, np.NaN]).rolling(3).apply(np.argmin)[2]                                                                                                                                                                                                            
Out[3]: nan
```

Why do these two calculations give different results?

### Original case

Trying to improve [my solution for rolling `idxmin/max`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65526535/3246135), I hit the following issue.

```py
In [1]: index = map(chr, range(ord('a'), ord('a') + 10))

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame((10 * np.random.randn(10, 3)).astype(int), index=index)

In [3]: df[0][3:4] = np.NaN

In [4]: df                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
Out[4]: 
      0   1   2
a   0.0  -2  -7
b  -6.0   7   7
c   7.0 -23 -13
d   NaN   4  -6
e   7.0  19  10
f  -3.0   4  -2
g   9.0 -16  -2
h  13.0  15  -2
i   6.0   8   0
j  -9.0 -10  11

In [5]: df.rolling(3).apply(np.argmin)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Out[5]: 
     0    1    2
a  NaN  NaN  NaN
b  NaN  NaN  NaN
c  1.0  2.0  2.0
d  NaN  1.0  1.0
e  NaN  0.0  0.0
f  NaN  0.0  0.0
g  1.0  2.0  1.0
h  0.0  1.0  0.0
i  2.0  0.0  0.0
j  2.0  2.0  0.0

In [6]: np.argmin(pd.Series([-6.0, 7.0, np.NaN]))  # for index 'd', col 0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
Out[6]: 0
```

Shouldn't the manual application of `np.argmin` (for index `'d'`, column 0) give the same result as the corresponding rolling application? Why does the rolling application give me `NaN` instead of `0`?

Answer (score 0):

Of course, this is a RTFM case...

For DataFrame.rolling:

> min_periods (int, default None): Minimum number of observations in window required to have a value (otherwise result is NA). For a window that is specified by an offset, min_periods will default to 1. Otherwise, min_periods will default to the size of the window.

So:

```py
In [1]: np.argmin(pd.Series([-6.0, 7.0, np.NaN]))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
Out[1]: 0

In [2]: pd.Series([-6.0, 7.0, np.NaN]).rolling(3, min_periods=0).apply(np.argmin)[2]                                                                                                                                                                                             
Out[2]: 0.0
```