# Calculating a rolling idxmax when index is DatetimeIndex type in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to calculate the maximum of a column over a sliding window. [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70225288/11748994) provides a remedy that works when the index is numeric but I have DatetimeIndex object as my index. I do not want to create a new index column and solve my problem. Instead, I want to solve it directly using `rolling` because my data is big. Also, I do not want to use for. Here is a replicable example:

```
np.random.seed(0)
dtidx = pd.date_range(start='6/1/2022', end='6/2/2022', freq='min')
df = pd.DataFrame(np.cumsum(np.random.randn(len(dtidx))), index=dtidx)
ax = df.plot(figsize=(20, 4))
window = 60
df.rolling(window).max().plot(ax=ax)
plt.show()
df.rolling(window).apply(lambda x: x.idxmax())
```

[image]

**My question**

How can I catch only maximums and denote them on the graph. Currently, the maximums are denoted by 60 minutes delay.

Comment: Do you want the position of the maximums or the datetime at which the maximum occured?

Comment: @onyambu: I want the datetime at which a maximum happens so that I can use them and I can plot them on the underlying graph. To me, position and datetime that which maximum happens are the same.

Comment: in that case does `df.rolling(60).apply(lambda x: x.reset_index(drop = True).idxmax())`  help?

Comment: @onyambu: no. it gives me a wired answer. it provides ```2022-06-01 23:59:00  28.0
2022-06-02 00:00:00  27.0``` while the original signal is ```2022-06-01 23:59:00 -32.199537
2022-06-02 00:00:00 -32.052102```. Also, this new dataframe has the same length as the original one.  However, it should have less than 20 points.

Comment: No no dont look at the indices but rather the value within. Let me edit it for you

Comment: @onyambu: I am looking at values. I have included them in my previous comment. They are not right. I edited my previous comment. Please take a look at it.

Comment: checnk the indices it gives `df.iloc[df.rolling(60).apply(lambda x: x.reset_index(drop = True).idxmax()).dropna().astype(int).to_numpy().flatten()].index`

Comment: @onyambu: please check your answers and run them. This new line gives 1382 indices which is not right.

Comment: The size should be 1382. Note that the window is 60. So the values will be 1441-60+1. even when you do `df.rolling(window).max().dropna().size` should give you 1382

Comment: @onyambu: I think you are misunderstanding the problem. Just take a look at the picture, we have less than 20 local maximums. I want the coordinates of them. What you are providing to me is the orange curve that I have in my picture!

Answer (score 0):

According to [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50836425/11748994) you can do the following:

```
from scipy.signal import argrelextrema

window=20

max = df.iloc[argrelextrema(df.values, np.greater_equal, order=window)[0]]
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,4))
ax.scatter(max.index, max.values, color='r')
ax.plot(df.index, df.values, color='b')
plt.show()
```

[image]